# Time and speed of light in Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, coordinate-systems, time-dilation

Time running slower near a massive object, but the speed of light does not really change near a massive object, according to Relativity - it just curves. Is not *time* directly related to the speed of light in all time-related equations in the Theory of relativity, or I get it somehow wrong? The way I understand it s that time is always connected and relates to the speed of light. I am a bit confused about this and will be grateful to get some help!

Comment: Because of the [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity) there's no coordinate-independent answer to how fast one clock is ticking relative to another given clock at any given instant, so be careful about the idea that "time runs slow" (also note the speed of light is constant in local inertial frames, but in many global coordinate systems the speed varies). The only really objective comparison you can make is total elapsed time in a case where two clocks start at the same location, move apart on different paths through spacetime, and later reunite.

Comment: You have one misunderstanding. If you were to drill a tunnel through a planet, and shine a light through that tunnel, the light would indeed slow down. This is known as Shapiro delay. I asked a question about this just a few months ago. You can use the speed of light as a "ruler" to measure the speed of time. So time definitely does run slower near a planet, and that means that even the cesium atoms would vibrate slower relative to other places in space.

Comment: @foolishmuse This is the precise answer of my question, thank you!!! Now, does somebody happen to know what the exact mechanism empoyed here, is? I could only find mathematical descriptions of the observed fact, but nothing about **how** exactly gravitational sources cause the effect of sowering atoms' vibrations.

Comment: No one really knows how time dilation works.  The basic answer is that matter and energy cause time dilation.  And many experts consider that time dilation causes gravity.  I found myself asking that exact question 6 years ago.  So I've spent 6 years coming up with a theory.  You can download it here: https://vixra.org/abs/2202.0156   But keep in mind that this is just what I have come up with.   I'm not a physicist and there is a lot of speculation involved, and it is certainly not "accepted science" as is required on this Stack Exchange.  Have fun!

Comment: @ foolishmuse How cool! Do you mind to be contacted personally on this topic, are you In for discussions? I see there is an e-mail in the PDF document - is it valid? I will anyway need some time to read what's in the article to be able to ask adequate questions...

Comment: I'm happy to discuss it. Feel free to email me directly.

Comment: @AdelinaMitkova “*the speed of light does not really change near a massive object*” - This is incorrect. Light moves with the speed of time (we just call it “the speed of light”).

Comment: @safesphere Obviously, time and speed of light are somehow connected in scientific measurement. Do you claim here that *time* is a more basic phenomenon in nature than *propagation of EM waves*?

Comment: @AdelinaMitkova Not more basic, both are directly related. In the hyperbolic geometry of spacetime, time moves through space with the maximum possible speed. What moves with the same speed, remains in the same moment of time - doesn’t move in time. Photons don’t move in time, because they move with time. Light moves with the speed of time - the maximum possible speed. If I am at a station observing a train (of time), I can count train cars passing by me (seconds). If you’re in the train, you are always in the same car, your count is zero, because you move with the train (your time is stopped).

Comment: @safesphere Thanks for the clarification. Seems to me now that I get things right after all :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't think of time as a "thing" that "moves" or "runs". Think of it as just another direction in which *we* can move. People in different places in spacetime will have different definitions of how that movement splits into space and time.

As an analogy, suppose Alice and Bob are standing together at the equator, and Alice starts moving northwards at a constant speed. For Alice, she is always moving straight ahead (in the same direction) and at the same speed, but for Bob the amount by which she's moving northwards decreases, and indeed  when she reaches the North Pole her northwards velocity is 0.

Similarly, a clock near a massive object always moves forward in its time direction at 1 tick per second, but a distant clock in "empty space" will, because of the curvature of spacetime, view the clock as not moving as fast. That's not because the clocks are different, it's because their "time directions" are pointing differently.

Comment: What confuses me is this: The second is defined by taking the fixed numerical value of the caesium frequency - the transition frequency of the caesium atom of 9 192 631 770 Hz. Time running faster in space should mean more transitions possible per 1 second. Does a caesium atom in space really "tramble" faster than it does on earth?

Comment: As I said, time isn't a "thing" that "runs faster". Cesium atoms always tick at a certain frequency relative to their own time direction (their "proper time"). But a cesium atom on Earth has its time direction "curved" relative to a cesium atom in space -- just as in my example Alice and Bob end up with different directions for "north".

Comment: @AdelinaMitkova every clock always runs at the same rate as measured by all other clocks in the same frame. A person's intuitive sense of time, a stopwatch, or a Cs atomic clock are all clocks, and if they're all in the same frame, the ratio of how fast they tick never changes no matter how much you accelerate or how big the nearest mass is.

Comment: nice analogy @EricSmith!

Comment: Let an object move away with a relativistic speed, we know that by Doppler effect that the frequency decreases (redshift), this does not mean that the speed has decreased but it is the energy which has decreased (E'=h'=h/T'=hc/ λ') and it is the same thing the gravitational shift
 or Einstein shift
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift

Comment: @EricSmith It took me quite some time to understand your explaination - for me this field is still "deep physics" :D I finally got it! Can you further explain why exactly the time direction gets "curved" - is it the gravitational field that is affecting the Cs atoms somehow when these are closer to the gravity source, or the EMenergy that the massive objects itself emits all the time (the black-body radiation), or yet some other reason?

Comment: Spacetime is curved by matter and energy, in a way described by Einstein's field equations (general relativity). So the gravity field isn't affecting the Cs atoms, it's affecting the space and time around them

Comment: Is then the black-body emission of the massive object affecting the Cs atoms close to the source? Can energetic interactions between the Cs atoms and the massive object cause the Cs atoms to vibrate slower then Cs atoms far from any massive object (like, out in space)? (see comment from *foolishmuse* right under the initial question)

Comment: No, the effect is not an electromagnetic one, it's gravitational. Mass and energy warp spacetime. If you're asking "why", right now there's no answer -- it's like asking in Newton's theory "why do masses attract each other". They just do. The Cs atoms themselves are behaving just like every other Cs atoms in the universe. The only difference between the atoms is where (and when) they are.

Comment: For another analogy, imagine you measure the Eiffel tower using a coordinate system based on "straight up"  being defined in London. Then the tower in Paris will appear tilted towards the East, and shorter than you would expect. There's no physical cause for this, it's an artifact of the geometry and the coordinate systems in use.

Answer (score 1):

from your comment to Eric's fine answer, I think you do not really understand how the second is defined.

Please refer to the relevant [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesium_standard) page.
In particular....

> When the atom is irradiated with electromagnetic radiation having an
> energy corresponding to the energetic difference between the two
> sub-levels the radiation is absorbed and the atom is excited, going
> from the F = 3 sub-level to the F = 4 one. After a small fraction of a
> second the atom will re-emit the radiation and return to its F = 3
> ground state. From the definition of the second it follows that the
> radiation in question has a frequency of exactly 9.19263177 GHz,
> corresponding to a wavelength of about 3.26 cm and therefore belonging
> to the microwave range.

So an exited atom will emit a EM radiation at a very well defined frequency.
An observer with this atom sitting in a gravitational well (Earth, for example) with a receiver and an oscilloscope, will see a wiggling voltage on her screen. When she sees  9.19...billions crossings of the zero line in the up direction she says : "a second has elapsed!" according to her atomic clock.

However the same signal will proceed to outer space...far away in the almost flat asymptotic region. Another observer up there, with a receiver and oscilloscope will see the same 9.19..billions crossings of the zero line in the up direction, but... they will take more than a second by her own atomic clock.

Why is that? Well you know the gravitation red shift? Radiation originating in a gravitational well, is red-shifted (ie. has lower frequency) when received by a distant observer. So if the starting frequency was 9.19...GHz , it will be lower, say 9.10... GHz for the distant observer. So for the distant observer there will be fewer wiggles in her own "second" and 9.19...billion wiggles will take longer.

Why do we have gravitation red shift? Well Einstein reasoned the the photon , like any ascending projectile, will lose energy as it tries to leave a gravitational well. Since for a photon energy is proportional to frequency , it will have a lower frequency when arriving at the distant observer.

So, photons leaving a gravitational well lose energy, thus they "lose" frequency and since frequency is simply "number of wiggles divided by time" and the number of wiggles is the same for both observers, time has to "change" for the 2 observers.

Einstein made this reasoning when starting to understand General Relativity.

Comment: Thanks for this quite detailed explaination - it helped me realize a lot about time! If I understand correct, you are describing the scenario when one and the same traveling wave reaches the two clocs one after another. But can you tell me what would happen if both clocks are reached by two separate waves with absolutely the same wavelenght - 3,26cm - will it still take more than a second by the "outer-space" atomic clock to measure the same "number of wiggles" as the Earth-positioned clock? As far as I understand it, there **will** be difference between the two clocks in that case, too

Comment: HI, it is not clear to me the setup of the waves. Where do they start from? Let's say you have an emitter in "mid air" sending a spherical wave. This wave will be received down to "earth" blueshifted and "up in space" redshifted. So each observer will say that time is running faster or slower than time in mid air